# Can you take the Facebook login connection on iOS/Android App and automatically log a user in when they hit Facebook on a mobile browser?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

We have a mobile browser based application that uses Facebook login.

Users have to re-enter their Facebook login details in the browser even though they are already logged in on the mobile within the native Facebook iOS or Android App

Is there anyway for a user to avoid having to re-login to Facebook on the browser? For example logging in using the native Facebook iOS/Android app?

Comment: In short -  is there anyway for the SSO to detect that the user is going onto Facebook on the mobile browser

Comment: You can only use the SSO of Android with a native App afaik. Can also be a Phonegap App, but it will not work in the browser.